# Strange onkeydown values for arrow keys

Tags: javascript, onkeydown

I'm writing a game in Javascript. I expected that browsers might map arrow keys to different values, so my aim is to allow the user to initially map arrow keys and other keys that are used throughout the game, since everyones preferences will differ... and later reconfigure those key configurations if they choose to do so.

For the purpose of providing a MCVE, I've used the code `document.onkeydown = function(ev) { console.log(ev.keyCode); }` which can be easily pasted into the javascript console for any browser. I feel as though the onkeydown method is required, as it's the only one that will reliably be repeated as the key is held down, which is a behaviour that I desire.

When running Chrome 42.0.2311.152 m or IE11, pressing any of the arrow keys causes an event which prints 255, followed by an event which prints an actual keycode. When using Firefox 35.0.1, that's 0 followed by the actual keycode.

To rephrase, my problem is that there are two events raised per arrow keystroke, and the values for the two events differ wildly depending upon the browser. I suppose the first event is to indicate that an arrow (or otherwise control) key was pressed, and the second combines with it to provide a unique identifier for that control key.

Can I suppress the first event, in such a way that is compatible with all browsers now and into the future?

Alternatively, is there another event listener I can use that'll repeat as the key is held down, and work for any key with all browsers now and into the future?

Comment: its time to replace your faulty keyboard mate. or make sure that there are no custom key/macro bindings set by your keyboard hardware/software. this issue does not happen on a simple keyboard. tested on latest chrome/firefox/IE

Comment: The keydown event only fires once in here. Are you sure you aren't binding an extra listener somewhere in your code?

Comment: @Banana That's strange. Different values for different software seems to indicate it's a software thing, but you could be right. I'll give it a test on a different computer.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour it might also be as alfonso suggested. you might be attaching an additional event listener for the keydown elsewhere in your code. try it on this page first, right here open the developer console ans stick the code line from your question and see if the result is any different.

Comment: @Banana I've tried on Google, in both Firefox and Chrome. Trying IE now. -shrugs-

Comment: Updated to include IE11.

Comment: Click the `source` at the right most of Console to find out which code outputs 255/0 and actual key code.

Comment: @Aprian As you can see by the origin line numbers to the right hand side, both outputs come from the same line: http://i.imgur.com/0vXTaUD.png